# input:required:invalid for decimals

Tags: css

I want my input box to display a red border unless the input box contains a value.

It works as I desire for whole numbers (0, 1, 2, 3 ...) but not for decimals (0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ...).

How can I make the input box remove the red border when the box contains any number?

```css
input {
  margin: 0 10px 20px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 75px
}

input:required:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<input id = "enterThing"
  type        = "number"
  class       = "form-control formBlock"
  min         = "0"
  max         = "10.5"
  required/
>
<input id = "sliderThing"
  class   = "slider"
  type    = "range"
  step    = ".1"
  value   = "0"
  min     = "0"
  max     = "10.5"
  oninput = "enterThing.value = sliderThing.value"
>
```

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me in Chrome without any changes. After entering a number the red border disappears. Though you might want to consider using the `:empty` and `:focus-visible` pseudo-classes too in other rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `step` attribute to the input type number too.

```css
input {
  margin: 0 10px 20px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 75px
}

input:required:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<input id = "enterThing"
  type        = "number"
  class       = "form-control formBlock"
  min         = "0"
  max         = "10.5"
  step        = "0.1"
  required/
>
<input id = "sliderThing"
  class   = "slider"
  type    = "range"
  step    = ".1"
  value   = "0"
  min     = "0"
  max     = "10.5"
  oninput = "enterThing.value = sliderThing.value"
>
```

Comment: The default step is one... And it seems that validation is accounting it. It was not obvious ;)